# Using sed to match only the first sequence of numbers from an environment variable

Tags: bash, sed

I have an environment variable containing a branch name as follows:

`feature/PROJ-12233-some-other-text-potential-12`

I would like to capture only 12233 above using `sed` -- `grep` does not work :-(

Comment: please add the command you tried.. also, add some details about the type of inputs likely to occur, is it always second field (assuming `-` as field separator), is it always the first sequence of digits, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the general case you want to extract the first sequence of digits from a string and ignore anything else

```
s="feature/PROJ-12233-some-other-text-potential-12"
```

`grep` is just fine:

```
echo "$s" | grep -o "[0-9]*" | head -1
12233
```

or with `awk`

```
awk '{gsub(/[^[0-9]]*/," "); print $1}' <<< "$s"
12233
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\+\).*/\1/' file
```

Replace everything that is not a number, followed by a number, followed by anything else by the matched number.